# storing file name to database after uploading to ftp server using java

Tags: java, sql, file-upload, ftp

i am developing an utility which will upload files to ftp server. The code is running right. But now i want to save file name to sql database at server side. Please help me with this. below is the code for file upload. It is running right.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import org.apache.commons.net.PrintCommandListener;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

public class FTPUploader {

    FTPClient ftp = null;

    public FTPUploader(String host, String user, String pwd) throws Exception{
        ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
        int reply;
        ftp.connect(host);
        reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ftp.disconnect();
            throw new Exception("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
        }
        ftp.login(user, pwd);
        ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    }
    public void uploadFile(String localFileFullName, String fileName, String hostDir)
            throws Exception {
        try(InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(localFileFullName))){
             String       ss=hostDir+"/swaps";
                    this.ftp.makeDirectory(ss);
                     boolean changeWorkingDirectory = ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(ss);
        //this.ftp.storeFile(ss + fileName, input);
                     if(changeWorkingDirectory)
                this.ftp.storeFile(fileName, input);
        }
    }

    public void disconnect(){
        if (this.ftp.isConnected()) {
            try {
                this.ftp.logout();
                this.ftp.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException f) {
                // do nothing as file is already saved to server
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Start");
        FTPUploader ftpUploader = new FTPUploader("www.web.com", "swaswa", "swaswa");
        //FTP server path is relative. So if FTP account HOME directory is "/home/pankaj/public_html/" and you need to upload 
        // files to "/home/pankaj/public_html/wp-content/uploads/image2/", you should pass directory parameter as "/wp-content/uploads/image2/"
        ftpUploader.uploadFile("D:\\o.jpg", "qq.jpg", "");
                ///netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable
        ftpUploader.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't you have any code server side? Have you tried anything?

Comment: no, ihave not tried anything. can you please help??

Comment: No, sorry. It would be too much work and I'm not your employee. After trying to do it, you can come back and ask us for concrete doubts and I will be happy to help you.

Comment: can u gve me nay link??